# How can I stop notifications from an unknown Facebook account to my new phone?

Tags: facebook, notifications

I have a new phone and the phone number seems to have been used before, by someone who wanted a notification whenever they logged in to Facebook.

*Note: I do not have the phone that person had, so I can't go into the Facebook app or anything like that. I don't know their name, either.*

I am getting texts at all hours of the day and night telling me "Your Facebook account was accessed from an unknown browser" etc. I want these to stop, but obviously I can't contact the person and say "you forgot to turn off your login notifications". How can I make these texts stop?

Comment: This might be a little nefarious, but could be a good object lesson: Go through the "forgot password" process to get the password reset based on the phone. Log in to their account and remove the phone number. Presumably they'll then use the password recovery to regain control of the account.

Answer (score 2):

Reply with “OFF” to the Facebook texts and it should stop. More info here on [this Facebook support](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200848758599544) page.

If that doesn't work, I would contact Facebook support. They are not super responsive but they can solve problems. You could also block texts from the Facebook number. This is more of the nuclear option so try to work thru Fb first. More info on how to block numbers [here](http://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/971686).

For future reference, all I did was Google "someone used my phone number for Facebook" and the Facebook support article was the top result.

Edit: As per Al E's suggestion, you could try associating your phone number with your account. I might trigger a verification process to see who has control of that number and might fix the problem.

Comment: While this stops the texts, it doesn't solve the underlying problem that my phone number is associated with a stranger's facebook. And I tried contacting fb support and cannot figure out how on earth to do that. Just worthless forums without answers. I would like to disconnect the number if that is possible.

Comment: Disassociating that number is the ultimate solution, you are correct.  I don't know how to get thru Fb support faster. Sorry.

Comment: I don't know how to get through to fb support **at all** - can't find an email, a phone number, anything. Wherever that info is it's well hidden.

Comment: Yay. They are notoriously bad. With 750 million users and 7,000 employees that is around 100,000 people to support per employee. They try to make it hard to get ahold of them. Sorry.

Comment: @Kate: What happens if you add the phone number to your own Facebook account? Do you get any sort of warning about it existing on another account? Perhaps with an option to turn it off?

Comment: @AlE. I don't want to connect my facebook to the phone in general, and especially not if that might somehow reveal me to the old person.

Comment: @Kate: You could always disassociate it again later.

Comment: +1 to @AlE. Just add the number to your own account, then disassociate it later. This may trigger a verification and could fix the problem.